# Firefox not registering event handlers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I have tried everything, and this Javascript code does not work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
console.log('kk');
var box=document.getElementById('box');
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

setTimeout(document.getElementById('msgline').style.opacity=1,1000);

body.addEventListener('dragenter',function(e){

    console.log('kkkkkkk!');
    box.style.transform=box.style.webkitTransform='rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(180deg)';
    enters++;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});

body.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;});

body.addEventListener('dragleave',function(e){

    if(--enters===0)
        box.style.transform=box.style.webkitTransform='rotateX(-20deg)';

});

body.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
    var files=e.dataTransfer.files;
    [].forEach.call(files,function(file){
            convertToMOSTEM(file);
        }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

});

At least not in Firefox. It is meant to register event handlers on `body` for an html5 drag. It should apply some styles to `box` when you drag over the body, and remove them on dragleave. It should also call `convertToMOSTEM` whenever a file is dropped. It logs kk to the console, meaning that the code inside the `DOMContentLoaded` was executed. However, it never animates the box or logs kkkkkkkk! to the console when I drag over or leave and when I drop it attempts to open the file. I am pretty sure that the event handlers are never defined. It works in Safari and Chrome. What is the problem?

Comment: What happens if instead of selecting `body` using `getElementsByTagName`, you simply use `document.body`?

Comment: @JulianH.Lam just tried that, it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It seems random (maybe even a bug?), but it was the setTimeout call. Comment it out, and it works fine!

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't see that line. Looks like you're using the `setTimeout` function incorrectly. Everything before `,1000` should be wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: didn't know that. I thought that you only needed to do that if you have more than one statement in it

Comment: Possibly, which may definitely explain why it works in some browsers but not others. The first argument in `setTimeout` expects either a string to an already existing function, or a function reference (or, of course, an anonymous function).